# Bypass a step on Azure Blueprint

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create a conditional azure blueprint.

I added `"condition": "[parameters ('SkipThisComponent')]"` at resource level.

It works means it bypassed the deployment, but at the end the assignment fails, since the component hasn't been deployed.

[image: Error Print Screen]

Is there a way to bypass a step on Azure Blueprint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

In the ARM template, set the condition of the resource which references Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/test to:

`[not(parameters('SkipThisComponent'))]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is at Azure Blueprint Level rather than the Arm template level.

Comment: In that case you could edit the artifact that is trying to reference the skipped resource and add `"condition": "[not(parameters('SkipThisComponent'))]"`

Comment: No it didn't work... It si related to the Azure blueprint

Comment: The error is telling you it is looking for a resource that you have skipped.  The only reason it would be looking for this resource is if the blueprint has a dependency on it being there. Ie. you have an RM template with a resource that has a dependsOn, or the skipped resource is explicitly being referred to by another resource.  A blueprint a nothing but a collection of ARM templates and the exact same concepts apply, it's just blueprints give you a bit of extra management and deployment capabilities.